# Python unit test running error using flask_restful

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

Following is the directory structure. I am trying to run and i get the following error and below is my test_vuln.py code. The app runs fine by itself and it also runs without any errors when i do python tests/test_vuln.py.

```
python -m unittest tests/test_vuln.py 

/Users/skdandavathi/.local/share/virtualenvs/vuln-GqWMRh7_/bin/python: No module named python -m unittest .

vuln
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── README.md
├── client.py
├── main.py
├── requirements.txt
├── resources
│   ├── api.py
│   ├── errors.py
│   └── routes.py
├── static
│   ├── cve.csv
│   ├── example_expected_results.json
│   ├── example_post_data.json
│   └── out.json
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_vuln.py
```

How do i run unit tests here, please help. thanks

```
import unittest
import json
import sys
import os
sys.path.append("/Users/skdandavathi/Documents/Karthik/projects/vuln")
from main import app

class TestVulnApi(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = app.test_client()
        print(self.app)

    def test_get_error(self):
        response = self.app.get(ENDPOINT)
        data = json.loads(response.get_data())
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 401)



    def tearDown(self):
        # delete anything above
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the last lines of code, `if __name__ == '__main__':`,
have the purpose of running testing files like this `python tests/test_vuln.py`.
If you want to run this program`python -m unittest tests/test_vuln.py`, try erasing the lines above. So:

With:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

Run the script with the following command: `python tests/test_vuln.py`. And without it, run the script with the following command:`python -m unittest tests/test_vuln.py`. Helpful info in [link 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6tNS--WetLI).

Comment: Thanks for the response. i erased the code as suggested and still see the error./Users/skdandavathi/.local/share/virtualenvs/vuln-GqWMRh7_/bin/python: No module named python -m unittest

Comment: That's weird. Look, [here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/issues/104) they have a similiar problem, a don't get a solution. Try to run it with pytest: First, run  `pip install pytest`, then run the script like this  `py.test -v tests/test_vuln.py`. Got this from [link](https://developer.lsst.io/v/DM-7552/coding/python_testing.html).

Comment: What is your python version? I read that unittest depends also of the python version. So, in importing line, you can try something like this: `import sys
if sys.version_info[:2] <= (2, 6):
    import unittest2 as unittest
else:
    import unittest`. Got this from [here](https://github.com/laserson/impyla/commit/b24aa186e5732641c16bcc23d504dceee3aeac5a)

Comment: python version is 3.6 .. will look at pytest but pytest does not have a way to run everything in one class right if i am correct